# Flutter nested cubit not getting recreated

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a flutter app using BLoC architecture with the flutter_bloc package.

Part of my widget tree looks like this:

```
class ItemsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        BlocBuilder<FirstCubit, FirstState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: state.items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Item item = state.items[index];
                    return BlocProvider<SecondCubit>(
                      create: (_) => SecondCubit(item),
                      child: ItemWidget(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

So, the `FirstCubit`'s state `FirstState` contains a list of `Item`s. Inside the `BlocBuilder`, I have got another `BlocProvider` for the `ItemWidget`, because this widget depends on the `SecondCubit`'s state, that contains an `Item`. Now, when the `FirstCubit`'s state changes, I want to rebuild the whole widget tree. Because the items could change completely, I want to recreate all the `SecondCubit`s as well. But here is my problem: The `create` function of the nested `BlocProvider`s only gets called when the `BlocBuilder` first gets build, but doesn't get called on the rebuilds. Is that a wanted behavior? How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Give your `ListView.builder` a key, something like `ListView.builder(key: UniqueKey())`, and every time `BlocBuilder` rebuilds the widget tree, it will force the `ListView` to be rebuilt.